# how to setup catalog synchronization

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

i'm trying to setting up catalog replication staged->online I've created the sync job, that finishes successfully, but in online catalog nothing is created.

Any suggestion?

Thanks Marco

Answer (score 0):

In general the SetupSyncJobService is used to create SyncJobs. Maybe its better to use that class to create your sync job?

Did you set the root types? Root types are all item types that should be copied from staged to online catalog. So if you want to copy products from staged to online catalog, there should be an entry "Product" in the root types list. The SetupSyncJobServices creates all root types for you so you don't need to bother. Perhaps you can compare the setup of your sync job to another sync job set up by the SetupSyncJobService and match the configuration to it.

Comment: i've product in section "Root types" so SyncItemJob shoud be correct.

Comment: What user did you configure for the sync? Does it have the read/write rights for both catalogs?

Comment: I'm using ADMIN user

Comment: Did you configure languages in your catalog versions? Is your admin user or admingroup usergroup registered as users with read/write permission in the catalog versions? I just set up a new catalog with online and staged version as well as a sync job using backoffice. Worked perfectly fine

Comment: i've no language in my catalog versions....admin user is the standard one, so can read/write everything

Comment: Open your catalog versions in hmc/backoffice. Open tab "Permissions" and add admin group to both users with read and write permissions. Then you can sync your products. But you also need languages. Otherwise the product will have no content. If that does not help, please share your log.

Comment: now i'm able to sync product catalog, but not content catalog